# Métodos de DevExpress a Windows Forms

Tags: c#, devexpress

Tengo este foreach donde esta **gridView1.GetSelectedRows()** y **gridView1.GetDataRow(i)** este gridView1 es de  **DevExpress** y creo que el método también lo que pasa es que ya no tengo licencia  para  **DevExpress**  entonces me toco cambiar todo para Windows Form pero lo que no he podido hacer es cambiar este gridView1 por el dataGridView1 normal de Windows Form y llamar estos metodos  **gridView1.GetSelectedRows()**, **gridView1.GetDataRow**

Así funciona bien con **DevExpress**

```
 foreach (int i in gridView1.GetSelectedRows())
                {
                    DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(i);
 MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString());
```

Así estoy tratando de quitar ese gridView1 para remplazarlo por el dataGridView1  pero no se cual es el remplazo de esos métodos **gridView1.GetSelectedRows()**, **gridView1.GetDataRow** por que no funcionan con dataGridView1 como seria el remplazo de estos dos? en ese mismo foreach

```
 foreach (int i in  dataGridView1. ---    )
            {
                DataRow row =  dataGridView1. ----  (i);
            MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString());
```

**Método completo**

```
   private void Btn_Actualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            foreach (int i in gridView1.GetSelectedRows())
            {
                DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(i);
                MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString());

                string sql= "Update tblmvto_lotes set TipoCanal ='" + Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)+ "'  where codlote='"+ row[0].ToString() + "' and  animal=" + row[1].ToString()+"";
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sql1))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        //StrSql = "select id_ti_ser,cod_dat_equipo,codigo_usu,id_area,id_sede,id_tecnico,obseraciones from tbl_movi_datos_gene where  cod_dat_equipo ='" + codigo + "' or codigo_usu = '" + cedula + "'";
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandText = sql;
                        cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        gridControl1.DataSource = Cargar_infromacion_porcisof(sql1);
                        gridControl1.Refresh();
                        MessageBox.Show(" Se actualizo el lote " + row[0].ToString() + " y el animal " + row[1].ToString() + "  y  se le asigno " + comboBox1.SelectedText);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    MessageBox.Show("Error :" +ex.Message);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Que es lo que hace?, solo recorres el grid para mostrar el dato de la fila?

Comment: Es para hacer una actualización  de la fila del data grid subí, el método completo.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, si entendi tu metodo quedaría algo asi:

```
private void Btn_Actualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        foreach (DataGridViewRow i in gridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow row = i[0].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(row);

            string sql= "Update tblmvto_lotes set TipoCanal ='" + Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)+ "'  where codlote='"+ i[0].Value.ToString() + "' and  animal=" + i[1].Value.ToString()+"";
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sql1))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    //StrSql = "select id_ti_ser,cod_dat_equipo,codigo_usu,id_area,id_sede,id_tecnico,obseraciones from tbl_movi_datos_gene where  cod_dat_equipo ='" + codigo + "' or codigo_usu = '" + cedula + "'";
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    gridControl1.DataSource = Cargar_infromacion_porcisof(sql1);
                    gridControl1.Refresh();
                    MessageBox.Show(" Se actualizo el lote " + i[0].Value.ToString() + " y el animal " + i[1].Value.ToString() + "  y  se le asigno " + comboBox1.SelectedText);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                MessageBox.Show("Error :" +ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No se puede aplicar la indización con [] a una expresión del tipo 'DataGridViewRow', me sale esto entre  i[0]

Comment: Perdón, cambialo asi: i.cells[0].value.tostring()

Comment: Me sigue saliendo :(  No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'string' en System.Data.DataRow

Comment: A ver ponlo asi: Convert.ToString(i.Cells[0].Value);

Comment: Ya encontré la solución    foreach (DataGridViewRow i in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataRow row = ((DataRowView)i.DataBoundItem).Row;
                MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString());